# Multivariate and high-dimensional data, are they the same?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, large-data, high-dimensional

I read about the multivariate and high-dimensional data set. I found that the multivariate data is the data with more than 3 variables. In addition, the high-dimensional data is the data with a large number of variables. So, for me, the multivariate and high-dimensional data set are the same, is that correct? I think, do not know if it is correct or not, the multivariate data is a data with more than 3 variables but the number of observation is quite small (300 to 500 observations). However, high-dimensional data is the data with a large number of variables (10 to 100 or even larger) and a large number of observations (1000 observations). Is that correct?

Comment: `multivariate data is the data with more than 3 variables` No. Please read the tag [multivariate-analysis] info. As well as [high-dimensional] tag.

Comment: @ttnphns thank you for your comment and I am really sorry if I use a wrong tag. I actually have to work with multivariate and high-dimensional analysis.

Answer (score 1):

What is considered 'high' in high-dimensional is a futile discussion in my opinion. However, **uni**variate, **bi**variate and **multi**variate usually refer to the number of *outcome* variables.

High-dimensional data analysis is a term more often used for dealing with things specific to a large number of *explanatory* variables, or parameters. For example:

- Inability to perform matrix inversion and most forms of decomposition when $n < p$;
- Increasingly sparser coverage of the sampling space with growing dimensions;
- The [combinatorial explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_explosion)

A multivariate approach, *can* but need not involve these issues. You can have multiple outcome variables with only a handful of explanatory variables. You can also have a high-dimensional multivariate problem.

---

Tangentially related, for a classification task consisting of **two** classes, the outcome can be argued to follow a **bi**nomial distribution, whereas a multi-class classification task can be argued to follow a **multi**nomial distribution.